# OpenNebula: Can't create a host - Could not resolve hostname

Tags: ssh, cloud, cloud-computing, cloud-hosting, opennebula

I'm having trouble launching a host in Open nebula. Is is because I can't merge the front end with hosts i.e start off with one server and build from there. Do I have to start with 3 or 4 servers?

My error log when I try to create a host:

```
Fri Mar  8 15:14:21 2013 [ReM][D]: TemplatePoolInfo method invoked
Fri Mar  8 15:14:23 2013 [ReM][D]: GroupPoolInfo method invoked
Fri Mar  8 15:14:26 2013 [ReM][D]: HostAllocate method invoked
Fri Mar  8 15:14:27 2013 [ReM][D]: HostInfo method invoked
Fri Mar  8 15:14:27 2013 [InM][I]: Monitoring host bac (3)
Fri Mar  8 15:14:28 2013 [InM][I]: Command execution fail: scp -r /var/lib/one/remotes/. bac:/var/tmp/one
Fri Mar  8 15:14:28 2013 [InM][I]: ssh: Could not resolve hostname bac: Name or service not known
Fri Mar  8 15:14:28 2013 [InM][I]: lost connection
Fri Mar  8 15:14:28 2013 [InM][I]: ExitCode: 1
Fri Mar  8 15:14:28 2013 [InM][E]: Error monitoring host 3 : MONITOR FAILURE 3 Could not update remotes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the most common pitfalls when configuring for the first time an host.

The [documentation](http://opennebula.org/documentation:rel3.8:host_guide) states:

> Before adding a host check that you can ssh to it without being prompt for a password

You can simply check for DNS configuration problems trying to connect to the remote host using the same hostname you would add with the onehost create command, from the oneadmin shell:

`$ ssh bac`

If you can reach the remote host shell, you are done. If not, check about your DNS configuration (or you may add a line in **/etc/hosts**)

Comment: Thanks. I also realized I had downloaded an old version of Open Nebula. I set the name as localhost and that seemed t0 solve that problem but I cant launch a VM quite yet.

Comment: Look for error messages in oned.log, and maybe open a new question ;) Also remember to mark as up and accept my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can start with only one server. Your problem is name resolution:

Fri Mar 8 15:14:28 2013 [InM][I]: ssh: **Could not resolve hostname bac**: Name or service not known